# EJS not outputting promised data using Twitter API V2

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to make a simple application using the Twitter API V2.

You enter a username in an input field, if the username exists, the info of that user gets displayed on the screen (user id, username, name, profile image, followers list).

Now on the sever side, I made a userInfo empty object that gets filled with user data whenever a post request has been sent with an existent username.

The problem is with the followers list, in EJS it doesn't show, sometimes it throws an error saying that followersList() is not a function, and sometimes it doesn't throw an error but it still doesn't display the followers, although all of the rest of the values are working!!

I don't understand why? I made sure I awaited everything and then send the whole userInfo object along with the render.

My routes code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Twitter = require('../twitter-init.js')

let userInfo = {};

// Request index page:
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {userInfo});
});


// Post username:
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    checkUsernameExists(username, res);
});


// Check user exists, if exists fill userInfo object with data:
function checkUsernameExists(username, res) {

    async function run() {
        const user = await (await Twitter.userByUsername(username, {"user.fields": ['public_metrics','profile_image_url']})).data;

        if(typeof user !== 'undefined') {
            userInfo = {
                exists: true,
                id: user.id,
                username: user.username,
                name: user.name,
                icon: user.profile_image_url,
                followersList: async function() {
                    try{
                        return await Twitter.followers(user.id, {"user.fields": ['public_metrics','profile_image_url']})
                    } catch(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    }

    run().then(() => res.redirect('/'));
    
};

module.exports = router;
```

My EJS code (WITHOUT CALLING FOLLOWERSLIST FUNCTION):

```
<body>
    
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <label for="">Enter username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    

    <h3> ID: <%= userInfo.id %> </h3>
    <h3> NAME: <%= userInfo.name %> </h3>
    <h3> USERNAME: <%= userInfo.username %> </h3>
    <h3> ICON: <img src=<%= userInfo.icon %> alt=""> </h3>
    
</body>
```

Result working fine:

[image]

My EJS code (After calling followersList function):

```
<body>
    
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <label for="">Enter username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    

    <h3> ID: <%= userInfo.id %> </h3>
    <h3> NAME: <%= userInfo.name %> </h3>
    <h3> USERNAME: <%= userInfo.username %> </h3>
    <h3> ICON: <img src=<%= userInfo.icon %> alt=""> </h3>
    
    <h1>List of followers:</h1>
    
    <% userInfo.followersList().then(result => { %>
        <% result.data.forEach(user => { %>
            <%= user.username %>
        <% }); %>
    <% }) %>
    

</body>
```

It doesn't show the followers list:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're sending an empty object and you can't call a method like that from the template.

Try this: don't render if there are none, on the server execute a function that will get followers list, and then assign the list and render it as an array in the template.

Change routes code:

```
async function getFollowersList(user) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let followers;
        try {
            followers = await Twitter.followers(user.id, {
                "user.fields": ['public_metrics', 'profile_image_url']
            });
            resolve(followers);

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}


// Check user exists, if exists fill userInfo object with data:
function checkUsernameExists(username, res) {

    async function run() {
        const user = await (await Twitter.userByUsername(username, {"user.fields": ['public_metrics','profile_image_url']})).data;

        if(typeof user !== 'undefined') {

            // await followers
            const followers = await getFollowersList(user);

            userInfo = {
                exists: true,
                id: user.id,
                username: user.username,
                name: user.name,
                icon: user.profile_image_url,
                followersList: followers
            }
        }
    }

    run().then(() => res.redirect('/'));
    
};
```

Change template:

```
   <h1>List of followers:</h1>
    
    <% if(userInfo.followersList) { %>
        <% userInfo.followersList.forEach(user => { %>
            <%= user.username %>
        <% }); %>
    <% } %>
```